# Draw a rectangle on a image inside a canvas using mousemove event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle on an image that is inside canvas using mousemove event . But i am getting rectangle on the image with color filled in the rectangle because of clearRect . can anyone figure me out . how to draw a rectangle with just a border on the image . Below is the code that i followed to achieve it .

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    rect = {},
    drag = false;
 function init() {
  var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
   canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
   canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
   canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
 }
 function mouseDown(e) {
   rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
   rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
   drag = true;
 }
 function mouseUp() {
   drag = false;
 }
 function mouseMove(e) {
   if (drag) {
  rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
  rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY ;
  ctx.clearRect(rect.startX, rect.startY,rect.w,rect.h);
  draw();
   }
 }
 function draw() {
   ctx.clearRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
   ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
 }
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Draw a rectangle!</title>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You probably need to first clear the entire canvas using `clearRect`, then draw your `imageObj` immediately and finally, draw the stroke. All of this happening inside the `mouseMove` function so it basically keeps drawing these elements on a continuous basis.

Try this snippet below:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var rect = {};
var drag = false;
var imageObj = null;

function init() {
    imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function () { ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0); };
    imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    rect.startX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    rect.startY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() { drag = false; }

function mouseMove(e) {
    if (drag) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        rect.w = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - rect.startX;
        rect.h = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop) - rect.startY;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
    }
}
//
init();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for and helps you in some way.

P.S. I have intentionally applied the `red` colour on the stroke. You can remove it of course.