# Not being able to draw over canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle on a canvas in HTML5. If I use a canvas (with `fileList` as id) it is not getting displayed on the screen but if I used a div it is getting displayed. I want to display a rectangle over an image for annotation.

```js
function initDraw(canvas) {
  function setMousePosition(e) {
    var ev = e || window.event; 
    if (ev.pageX) { 
      mouse.x = ev.pageX + window.pageXOffset;
      mouse.y = ev.pageY + window.pageYOffset;
    } else if (ev.clientX) {
      mouse.x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
      mouse.y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    }
  };

  var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    startX: 0,
    startY: 0
  };
  var element = null;

  canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
    setMousePosition(e);
    if (element !== null) {
      element.style.width = Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
      element.style.height = Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
      element.style.left = (mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
      element.style.top = (mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
    }
  }

  canvas.onclick = function (e) {
    if (element !== null) {
      element = null;
      canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
      console.log("finsihed.");                        
    } else {
      console.log("begun.");
      mouse.startX = mouse.x;
      mouse.startY = mouse.y;
      element = document.createElement('div');
      element.className = 'rectangle';
      element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
      element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
      canvas.appendChild(element)
      canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
    }
  }
}

initDraw(document.getElementById('fileList'));
```

```css
.rectangle {
    border: 10px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black; 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="fileList" height="680px" width="800px"></canvas>
```

Comment: I did that too but still, nothing is getting displayed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw a rectangle on a image inside a canvas using mousemove event in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694870/draw-a-rectangle-on-a-image-inside-a-canvas-using-mousemove-event-in-javascript)

Comment: You are appending div to canvas element.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**
You seem to be asking how to overlap a DIV on a canvas.

**Answer**
Using your CSS, use the Z-Index to control how the layers overlap 
You will need to set one as Z-Index:0 and the DIV with Z-Index: of 1 or above;

**Don't forget:** that DIV elements without a height or width will **not** show show in Internet Explorer or Safari, so ensure your CSS includes a height and width

```js
function funStart(){
  if (typeof(document.getElementById("fileList").getContext("2d")) == undefined){
    console.log ("No HTML5 Canvas support");
    return;
  }else{
    var ctx = document.getElementById("fileList").getContext("2d");
  }

  ctx.canvas.height = 500;
  ctx.canvas.width = 500;
  ctx.fillStyle = "#F00";
  ctx.fillRect (0,0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.fill();

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", funStart(), false);
```

```css
.rectangle {
    border: 10px solid silver;
    color: white;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    left: 10;
    background-color: black; 
    z-index: 23;
}
canvas{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="fileList" height="680px" width="800px"></canvas>
<div id="messageBoard" class="rectangle">My DIV Message goes here</div>
```

Comment: @Durga:

I have marked my previous answer (which was provided via a mobile phone not a PC) for deletion, my previous answer Add a z-index to the css to bring the div forward or html element

Z-index:3;

For instance 

was very relevant as you can see, as the above demonstrates the code working :)

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the `.rectangle` `<div>` inside the `<canvas>`, but the children of `<canvas>` are used as fallback content. They'll only be displayed if the browser doesn't support `<canvas>`.

Instead, wrap the `<canvas>` in a positioned element to create a manageable [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/All_About_The_Containing_Block), and add the `.rectangle`s to that element:

```js
function initDraw(canvas) {
  function setMousePosition(e) {
    var ev = e || window.event;
    mouse.x = ev.offsetX;
    mouse.y = ev.offsetY;
  };

  var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    startX: 0,
    startY: 0
  };
  var element = null;

  canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
    setMousePosition(e);
    if (element !== null) {
      element.style.width = Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
      element.style.height = Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
      element.style.left = (mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
      element.style.top = (mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
    }
  }

  canvas.onclick = function (e) {
    if (element !== null) {
      element = null;
      canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
      console.log("finsihed.");                        
    } else {
      console.log("begun.");
      mouse.startX = mouse.x;
      mouse.startY = mouse.y;
      element = document.createElement('div');
      element.className = 'rectangle';
      element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
      element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
      canvas.closest('.canvaswrap').appendChild(element);
      canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
    }
  }
}

initDraw(document.getElementById('fileList'));
```

```css
.rectangle {
    border: 10px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.canvaswrap {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvaswrap">
  <canvas id="fileList" height="680" width="800"></canvas>
</div>
```

(Since we're now positioning relative to an element instead of the entire page, I changed your `setMousePosition` logic as well. I also added `box-sizing: border-box;` to the `.rectangle`s' styling so that they're not off the clicked coordinates by 10px, and `pointer-events: none;` so mouse events get sent to the `<canvas>` instead of being caught by overlaid `.rectangle`s. And `<canvas>`'s `height` and `width` attributes are defined to be in pixels; you don't need to put the "px" in them.)