# how to interactively draw a rectangular bounding box on an image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, npm, image-processing

In my project, I need a way to interactively draw multiple bounding boxes in an image when displayed inside a web browser. When the bounding boxes are drawn, I need to read out their coordinates. Can somebody propose a javascript library that can handle this task? I have no experience with frontend technologies like React or Angular and only have experiences with plain javascript.

Comment: Why do you tag this as java when you clearly mean javascript?

Comment: I tagged it with javascipt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer tells you how to draw boxes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65376701/6469130

Either:

- you should have the image drawn to the overlay canvas or
- you should have an image element beneath the canvas as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31696199/6469130)

What you need to add is storing the coordinates in `handleMouseUp()`. Logging example:

```
console.log(prevStartX, prevStartY, prevWidth, prevHeight);
```